# Sum pairs of numbers in array

Tags: java, beginner, array

This code takes a list of ints and sums their pairs, storing the summed pairs in an array `sumPairs`, then returning that array. If the supplied array `toSum` has an odd number of elements, it returns the `sumPairs` with the last element of the `toSum` as the last element of `sumPairs`. Any suggestions for improving my code, or accomplishing this task in a better way, would be most appreciated!

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] toSum) {
    int[] sumPairs = new int[toSum.length / 2 + toSum.length % 2]; 
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < toSum.length - 1; i+=2, j++) {
        sumPairs[j] = toSum[i] + toSum[i + 1];
    }
    if (toSum.length % 2 == 1 && sumPairs[sumPairs.length - 1] == 0) { 
        sumPairs[sumPairs.length - 1] = toSum[toSum.length - 1]; 
    }
    return sumPairs;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good! :)

The only thing I can spot is that the second condition for your `if` statement is unnecessary, as the first condition is all that is required. Therefore:

```
if (toSum.length % 2 == 1) {
    sumPairs[sumPairs.length - 1] = toSum[toSum.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version using Java 8 streams and lambdas. I personally find it slightly more readable, but I'm sure some will disagree.

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] toSum) {
    return IntStream.range(0, toSum.length)
            .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
            .map(n -> toSum[n] + (n + 1 == toSum.length ? 0 : toSum[n + 1]))
            .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll second hjk that this is already good. This entire process is \$O(N)\$ and there's no getting better than that. Only thing I'd personally do in your place  is add more white-space between statements for readability.

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] toSum) {
        int[] sumPairs = new int[toSum.length / 2 + toSum.length % 2]; 

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < toSum.length - 1; i+=2, j++) {
            sumPairs[j] = toSum[i] + toSum[i + 1];
        }

        if (toSum.length % 2 == 1) { 
            sumPairs[sumPairs.length - 1] = toSum[toSum.length - 1]; 
        }

        return sumPairs;
    }
```